# Altering mysql field throws 1064 Error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to alter the table field (called key) on my MySQL server as currently it is configured to accept only 255 characters and this is not sufficient for me, as I need 450.

I am using the following syntax, however that throws an error and I do not know why?

```
mysql> alter table gitolite_public_keys change key varchar(450);
```

Table structure:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id            | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| key_type           | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| title              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| identifier         | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| key                | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| active             | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 1       |                |
| delete_when_unused | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 1       |                |
| created_at         | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at         | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The error I get is :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key`
>   varchar(450)' at line 1

Comment: Try wrapping `key` in backticks.

Comment: `change` also renames your column, you want `modify` instead. [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: it's because you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key` varchar(450)' at line 1. key is a reserved word. you will have to wrap it in backticks.

Comment: @Siyual yup that worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your alter table syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE `gitolite_public_keys`
MODIFY COLUMN `key` varchar(450)
```